# I can't publish properly with Stream Publish using iframe facebook app

Tags: facebook, iframe

I have the following code:

```
`$attachment = array( 
            'message' => "test",
            'text' => 'Download',
            'name' => 'name', 
            'href' => 'http://www.mydomain.com', 
            'description' => 'description!', 
            'media' => array(array(
                'type' => 'mp3', 
                'src' => "http://www.mydomain.com/mp3.mp3", 
                'href' => 'http://www.mydomain.com/', 
                'title' => "title",
                'artist'=> 'artist',
                'album'=>  'the album')));
            $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);`
```

But when I publish the POST in my profile, it only shows the message "test". The mp3 file doesn't appear. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$attachment = array( 
            'message' => "test",
            'text' => 'Download',
            'name' => 'name', 
            'href' => 'http://www.mydomain.com', 
            'description' => 'description!', 
            'media' => array(
                'type' => 'mp3', 
                'src' => "http://www.mydomain.com/mp3.mp3", 
                'href' => 'http://www.mydomain.com/', 
                'title' => "title",
                'artist'=> 'artist',
                'album'=>  'the album'));
            $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);
```